# Creating a non blocking async gate in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, nonblocking

I need to create a gate to a resource in an async programming model so that one and only one thread can have access to a resource at any given time. Given the async programming model I would like the remaining requests to the resource to be queued so that I don't blok threads while waiting for the resource to become available.

I've looked and found a reader/writer gate in Jeffrey Richter's power threading library however I'm searching for something a bit different.

I have a vague idea that I would like the signature of the gate class to look like this:

```
public class Gate
{
  public IAsyncResult BeginEnterGate(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
  {
    ...
  }

  public GateRequest EndEnterGate(IAsyncResult result)
  {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

The returned gate request should be IDisposable and when disposed the gate would allow the next thread to use the resource.

```
public class GateRequest : IDisposable
{
  public void Dispose()
  {
    /* release gate */
  }
}
```

By having this I can utilize Jefrey Ricters powerthreading libary like so:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginFoo(string bar, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
  AsyncEnumerator ae = new AsyncEnumerator();
  return ae.BeginExecute(DoFoo(ae, bar), callback, state);
}

public void EndFoo(IAsyncResult result)
{
  AsyncEnumerator.FromAsyncResult(result).EndExecute(result);
}

private IEnumerator<int> DoFoo(AsyncEnumerator ae, string bar)
{
  gate.BeginEnterGate(ae.End(), null);
  yield return 1;
  var gateReleaser = gate.EndEnterGate(ae.DequeueAsyncResult());

  using (gateReleaser)
  {
    /* do work related to the resource */
  }
}
```

I might be staring myself blind at a certain way to solve this, so I'm also open to other suggestions.

Comment: "requests queued" == blocking.

Comment: Not necessarily, Hans. I encourage you to look at Jeffrey Richter's ReaderWriterGate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Power Threading Library has a SyncGate class that integrates in with the AsyncEnumerator. I think it provides the API you desire.

Comment: I must have missed that one. Never saw that class. Please include it in your samples for your power threading library since this is just what I've been searching for. Thanks, Mr. Richter.